# C# Library for Publishing and Consuming ActivityStrea.ms?

Tags: c#, argotic, activity-streams

I was just wondering if there was a C# client library for publishing & consuming [**ActivityStrea.ms**](http://activitystrea.ms) feeds.

As far as I know, the [**Argotic framework**](http://argotic.codeplex.com) is extensible and can be made to read [**ActivityStrea.ms**](http://activitystrea.ms), but I was hoping to find a more concrete/complete solution.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just joined the Argotic Team, and am in the middle of a major refactoring and update.  I'll keep ActivityStea.ms in mind when adding new extensions...

Comment: I know this was a while ago but my googling is not yielding much... did this ever get completed? Thanks in advance.